# Path for accessing Cisco-IOS-XE-Tunnel yang module in postman

Tags: cisco-ios

Recently I am working with RESTCONF on Postman.
Today I was trying to send HTTP request via postman to IOS-XE-Tunnel using the below path:

`https://XXX:XXX/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-tunnel:tunnel`

Usually this should return the data within the container "tunnel", however I am getting the following message:

`"error-message": "uri keypath not found", "error-tag": "invalid-value", "error-type": "application"`

My goal is to get the data within the leaf "bandwidth" from this yang module. Can anyone help me with a correct path?

Comment: The tunnel is going to have the bandwidth of the physical interface it uses to exit the router. Check the physical interface to get the bandwidth.

Comment: Hi, @Ron Maupin, I have tried using ietf-interface.yang which provides information for interfaces, but unfortunately it does not provide the bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this URL instead: `https://xxx:xxx/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/interface/Tunnel=1/bandwidth`

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your answer by editing it to add more details to make it more useful both for the original poster and future users. Typically short answers like this could provide reasoning why you believe this is the answer, more explanation about the concepts mentioned, references/links to supporting resources, or applicable examples.